# Mysql/Apache stops working once in a while

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, mysql

My problem: My webserver stops working once in a while. Apache still responds to requests, but it can't connect to mysql server. According to how I read the syslog it's because of insufficient RAM. Both apache and mysql runs on the same server.

I've bought much more RAM, but the problem persists. So I'm beginning to think that it is something else at play here.

Dump from interesting log lines, just before the problem accures

SYSlog:

```
Jul 30 19:28:54 ubuntu kernel: [1972483.311125] mysqld invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x201da, order=0, oom_adj=0, oom_score_adj=0 
Jul 30 19:28:54 ubuntu kernel: [1972483.311130] mysqld cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0 
Jul 30 19:28:54 ubuntu kernel: [1972483.311133] Pid: 14076, comm: mysqld Not tainted 3.2.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu 
Jul 30 19:28:54 ubuntu kernel: [1972483.311135] Call Trace: 
Jul 30 19:28:54 ubuntu kernel: [1972483.311144]  [<ffffffff810bfb3d>] ? cpuset_print_task_mems_allowed+0x9d/0xb0 
Jul 30 19:28:54 ubuntu kernel: [1972483.311148]  [<ffffffff8111a991>] dump_header+0x91/0xe0 
Jul 30 19:28:54 ubuntu kernel: [1972483.311149]  [<ffffffff8111ad15>] oom_kill_process+0x85/0xb0 
Jul 30 19:28:54 ubuntu kernel: [1972483.311151]  [<ffffffff8111b0ba>] out_of_memory+0xfa/0x220 
Jul 30 19:28:54 ubuntu kernel: [1972483.311154]  [<ffffffff81120aac>] __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x8dc/0x8f0 
Jul 30 19:28:54 ubuntu kernel: [1972483.311158]  [<ffffffff81157b36>] alloc_pages_current+0xb6/0x120 
Jul 30 19:28:54 ubuntu kernel: [1972483.311162]  [<ffffffff81117617>] __page_cache_alloc+0xb7/0xd0 
Jul 30 19:28:54 ubuntu kernel: [1972483.311164]  [<ffffffff81119874>] filemap_fault+0x234/0x3e0 
Jul 30 19:28:54 ubuntu kernel: [1972483.311167]  [<ffffffff8116e10b>] ? mem_cgroup_update_page_stat+0x2b/0x110 
Jul 30 19:28:54 ubuntu kernel: [1972483.311170]  [<ffffffff81139ec2>] __do_fault+0x72/0x550 
Jul 30 19:28:54 ubuntu kernel: [1972483.311174]  [<ffffffff816585ef>] ? schedule+0x3f/0x60 
Jul 30 19:28:54 ubuntu kernel: [1972483.311176]  [<ffffffff8113d55a>] handle_pte_fault+0xfa/0x200 
Jul 30 19:28:54 ubuntu kernel: [1972483.311178]  [<ffffffff8113da18>] handle_mm_fault+0x1f8/0x350 
Jul 30 19:28:54 ubuntu kernel: [1972483.311181]  [<ffffffff8165e020>] do_page_fault+0x150/0x520 
Jul 30 19:28:54 ubuntu kernel: [1972483.311185]  [<ffffffff81055efd>] ? set_next_entity+0xad/0xd0 
Jul 30 19:28:54 ubuntu kernel: [1972483.311207]  [<ffffffff810a0538>] ? do_futex+0xd8/0x1b0 
Jul 30 19:28:54 ubuntu kernel: [1972483.311209]  [<ffffffff810a071a>] ? sys_futex+0x10a/0x1a0 
Jul 30 19:28:54 ubuntu kernel: [1972483.311211]  [<ffffffff8165ac75>] page_fault+0x25/0x30 
Jul 30 19:28:54 ubuntu kernel: [1972483.311213] Mem-Info: 
Jul 30 19:28:54 ubuntu kernel: [1972483.311214] Node 0 DMA per-cpu: 
Jul 30 19:28:54 ubuntu kernel: [1972483.311216] CPU    0: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0 
Jul 30 19:28:54 ubuntu kernel: [1972483.311217] Node 0 DMA32 per-cpu: 
Jul 30 19:28:54 ubuntu kernel: [1972483.311218] CPU    0: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0 
Jul 30 19:28:54 ubuntu kernel: [1972483.311221] active_anon:326798 inactive_anon:109587 isolated_anon:0 
Jul 30 19:28:54 ubuntu kernel: [1972483.311221]  active_file:235 inactive_file:327 isolated_file:91 
Jul 30 19:28:54 ubuntu kernel: [1972483.311222]  unevictable:0 dirty:0 writeback:94 unstable:0 
Jul 30 19:28:54 ubuntu kernel: [1972483.311223]  free:13266 slab_reclaimable:2305 slab_unreclaimable:13295 
Jul 30 19:28:54 ubuntu kernel: [1972483.311224]  mapped:268 shmem:11 pagetables:36727 bounce:0 
Jul 30 19:28:54 ubuntu kernel: [1972483.311225] Node 0 DMA free:8344kB min:340kB low:424kB high:508kB active_anon:3616kB inactive_anon:3672kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:4kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:15648kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:88kB mapped:4kB shmem:0kB slab_reclaimable:24kB slab_unreclaimable:128kB kernel_stack:0kB pagetables:72kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:197 all_unreclaimable? yes 
Jul 30 19:28:54 ubuntu kernel: [1972483.311232] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 2000 2000 2000 
Jul 30 19:28:54 ubuntu kernel: [1972483.311234] Node 0 DMA32 free:44720kB min:44712kB low:55888kB high:67068kB active_anon:1303576kB inactive_anon:434676kB active_file:940kB inactive_file:1304kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):364kB present:2048244kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:288kB mapped:1068kB shmem:44kB slab_reclaimable:9196kB slab_unreclaimable:53052kB kernel_stack:4464kB pagetables:146836kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:9872 all_unreclaimable? yes 
Jul 30 19:28:54 ubuntu kernel: [1972483.311241] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0 
Jul 30 19:28:54 ubuntu kernel: [1972483.311242] Node 0 DMA: 22*4kB 15*8kB 13*16kB 6*32kB 3*64kB 1*128kB 3*256kB 3*512kB 3*1024kB 1*2048kB 0*4096kB = 8352kB 
Jul 30 19:28:54 ubuntu kernel: [1972483.311248] Node 0 DMA32: 292*4kB 98*8kB 211*16kB 176*32kB 464*64kB 0*128kB 0*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 1*4096kB = 44752kB 
Jul 30 19:28:54 ubuntu kernel: [1972483.311253] 16506 total pagecache pages 
Jul 30 19:28:54 ubuntu kernel: [1972483.311254] 15829 pages in swap cache 
Jul 30 19:28:54 ubuntu kernel: [1972483.311255] Swap cache stats: add 5050304, delete 5034475, find 192659029/193055410 
Jul 30 19:28:54 ubuntu kernel: [1972483.311256] Free swap  = 0kB 
Jul 30 19:28:54 ubuntu kernel: [1972483.311257] Total swap = 1046524kB 
Jul 30 19:28:54 ubuntu kernel: [1972483.317835] 524269 pages RAM 
Jul 30 19:28:54 ubuntu kernel: [1972483.317837] 11336 pages reserved 
Jul 30 19:28:54 ubuntu kernel: [1972483.317838] 113246 pages shared 
Jul 30 19:28:54 ubuntu kernel: [1972483.317839] 497331 pages non-shared
```

Log entry after the problem has occured:

```
Jul 30 19:28:57 ubuntu kernel: [1972483.318629] [14390]     0 14390    75449      258   0       0             0 apache2
Jul 30 19:28:57 ubuntu kernel: [1972483.318631] Out of memory: Kill process 32611 (mysqld) score 30 or sacrifice child
Jul 30 19:28:57 ubuntu kernel: [1972483.321875] Killed process 32611 (mysqld) total-vm:917688kB, anon-rss:10424kB, file-rss:68kB
Jul 30 19:29:09 ubuntu kernel: [1972497.928479] apache2 invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x280da, order=0, oom_adj=0, oom_score_adj=0
Jul 30 19:29:09 ubuntu kernel: [1972497.928485] apache2 cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
Jul 30 19:29:09 ubuntu kernel: [1972497.928489] Pid: 14205, comm: apache2 Not tainted 3.2.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu
Jul 30 19:29:09 ubuntu kernel: [1972497.928491] Call Trace:
Jul 30 19:29:10 ubuntu kernel: [1972497.928501]  [<ffffffff810bfb3d>] ? cpuset_print_task_mems_allowed+0x9d/0xb0
Jul 30 19:29:11 ubuntu kernel: [1972497.928505]  [<ffffffff8111a991>] dump_header+0x91/0xe0
Jul 30 19:29:12 ubuntu kernel: [1972497.928507]  [<ffffffff8111ad15>] oom_kill_process+0x85/0xb0
Jul 30 19:29:18 ubuntu kernel: [1972497.928509]  [<ffffffff8111b0ba>] out_of_memory+0xfa/0x220
Jul 30 19:29:19 ubuntu kernel: [1972497.928511]  [<ffffffff81120aac>] __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x8dc/0x8f0
Jul 30 19:29:19 ubuntu kernel: [1972497.928515]  [<ffffffff81116eb0>] ? sleep_on_page+0x20/0x20
Jul 30 19:29:19 ubuntu kernel: [1972497.928520]  [<ffffffff81159663>] alloc_pages_vma+0xb3/0x190
Jul 30 19:29:19 ubuntu kernel: [1972497.928522]  [<ffffffff81139bdc>] do_anonymous_page.isra.38+0x7c/0x2f0
Jul 30 19:29:19 ubuntu kernel: [1972497.928524]  [<ffffffff8113d641>] handle_pte_fault+0x1e1/0x200
Jul 30 19:29:19 ubuntu kernel: [1972497.928526]  [<ffffffff81142154>] ? vma_adjust+0x464/0x490
Jul 30 19:29:19 ubuntu kernel: [1972497.928528]  [<ffffffff8113da18>] handle_mm_fault+0x1f8/0x350
Jul 30 19:29:19 ubuntu kernel: [1972497.928530]  [<ffffffff811411a9>] ? find_vma+0x49/0x70
Jul 30 19:29:19 ubuntu kernel: [1972497.928534]  [<ffffffff8165e020>] do_page_fault+0x150/0x520
Jul 30 19:29:19 ubuntu kernel: [1972497.928538]  [<ffffffff81012728>] ? __switch_to+0x138/0x360
Jul 30 19:29:19 ubuntu kernel: [1972497.928541]  [<ffffffff81055efd>] ? set_next_entity+0xad/0xd0
Jul 30 19:29:19 ubuntu kernel: [1972497.928543]  [<ffffffff8105609a>] ? finish_task_switch+0x4a/0xf0
Jul 30 19:29:19 ubuntu kernel: [1972497.928547]  [<ffffffff81657f9c>] ? __schedule+0x3cc/0x6f0
Jul 30 19:29:19 ubuntu kernel: [1972497.928549]  [<ffffffff8165ac75>] page_fault+0x25/0x30
Jul 30 19:29:19 ubuntu kernel: [1972497.928551] Mem-Info:
Jul 30 19:29:19 ubuntu kernel: [1972497.928552] Node 0 DMA per-cpu:
Jul 30 19:29:19 ubuntu kernel: [1972497.928554] CPU    0: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Jul 30 19:29:19 ubuntu kernel: [1972497.928555] Node 0 DMA32 per-cpu:
Jul 30 19:29:19 ubuntu kernel: [1972497.928556] CPU    0: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Jul 30 19:29:19 ubuntu kernel: [1972497.928559] active_anon:324675 inactive_anon:108699 isolated_anon:2590
Jul 30 19:29:19 ubuntu kernel: [1972497.928559]  active_file:136 inactive_file:319 isolated_file:32
Jul 30 19:29:19 ubuntu kernel: [1972497.928560]  unevictable:0 dirty:0 writeback:256 unstable:0
Jul 30 19:29:19 ubuntu kernel: [1972497.928561]  free:13266 slab_reclaimable:2257 slab_unreclaimable:13383
Jul 30 19:29:19 ubuntu kernel: [1972497.928561]  mapped:145 shmem:14 pagetables:37093 bounce:0
Jul 30 19:29:19 ubuntu kernel: [1972497.928563] Node 0 DMA free:8344kB min:340kB low:424kB high:508kB active_anon:2728kB inactive_anon:2752kB active_file:8kB inactive_file:124kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):1104kB isolated(file):0kB present:15648kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:76kB mapped:0kB shmem:0kB slab_reclaimable:24kB slab_unreclaimable:132kB kernel_stack:0kB pagetables:164kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:4232 all_unreclaimable? yes
Jul 30 19:29:19 ubuntu kernel: [1972497.928569] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 2000 2000 2000
Jul 30 19:29:19 ubuntu kernel: [1972497.928571] Node 0 DMA32 free:44720kB min:44712kB low:55888kB high:67068kB active_anon:1295972kB inactive_anon:432044kB active_file:536kB inactive_file:1152kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):9256kB isolated(file):128kB present:2048244kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:948kB mapped:580kB shmem:56kB slab_reclaimable:9004kB slab_unreclaimable:53400kB kernel_stack:3168kB pagetables:148208kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:6289 all_unreclaimable? yes
Jul 30 19:29:19 ubuntu kernel: [1972497.928578] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0
Jul 30 19:29:19 ubuntu kernel: [1972497.928580] Node 0 DMA: 4*4kB 4*8kB 13*16kB 7*32kB 5*64kB 1*128kB 3*256kB 3*512kB 3*1024kB 1*2048kB 0*4096kB = 8352kB
Jul 30 19:29:19 ubuntu kernel: [1972497.928585] Node 0 DMA32: 29*4kB 41*8kB 259*16kB 221*32kB 453*64kB 0*128kB 0*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 1*4096kB = 44748kB
Jul 30 19:29:19 ubuntu kernel: [1972497.928590] 20810 total pagecache pages
Jul 30 19:29:19 ubuntu kernel: [1972497.928592] 20308 pages in swap cache
Jul 30 19:29:19 ubuntu kernel: [1972497.928593] Swap cache stats: add 5083803, delete 5063495, find 192661978/193059753
Jul 30 19:29:19 ubuntu kernel: [1972497.928594] Free swap  = 0kB
Jul 30 19:29:19 ubuntu kernel: [1972497.928595] Total swap = 1046524kB
Jul 30 19:29:19 ubuntu kernel: [1972497.935591] 524269 pages RAM
Jul 30 19:29:19 ubuntu kernel: [1972497.935593] 11336 pages reserved
Jul 30 19:29:19 ubuntu kernel: [1972497.935594] 93848 pages shared
Jul 30 19:29:19 ubuntu kernel: [1972497.935595] 495184 pages non-shared
```

Mysql error log doesn't provide any additional info.

What could possibly cause this problem, and what could i do to fix it?
If I reboot the server, the problem goes away a couple of weeks.

**EDIT**

/proc/swaps:

```
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/vda5                               partition   1046524 0   -1
/swapfile.img                           file        3145724 0   -2
```

Comment: From your stackoverflow user page I can see, that you practically _don't_ _vote_. It is highly improductive behavior - essentially, you don't reward the people helping you. Clicking on a triangle, it can't be so hard! Please, do it more often!

Comment: I give credit when credit is due, I do vote as you can see on my stackoverflow page hence i think your comment was uncalled for.

Comment: An 1G swap partition for a 2G system is imho small, but shouldn't cause such troubles. For the debug, you need to have this /swapfile.img, but later after the fix you can turn it off. I suggest to ask a new question, how can we enable mysql-slow.log. Your small swapfile, and the absence of a such log data means your system has multiple troubles, which need to be fixed step by step. The mysql-slow and this swap fix won't be probably the last problems.

Comment: I've enabled the slow log. Now i'll need to wait until the problem reaccures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clearly a mysql problem. The monit solution in banyek's answer is good, but it is only a symptomatical treatment and doesn't handles the cause.

Second: more ram is not enough. Enable a lot of swap (if I see correctly, you have 2Gig of ram and a 64bit system - maybe a 4 gig of swap will be enough). It is *important*. No, enabling swap won't make your system slower, it is a common misconception. But your system will be a little bit *faster* (it isn't a joke, I will explain it in comment if you wish), and of course much more stable.

Sometimes the swap of your system won't be enabled. Check in `/proc/swaps` to see if there is a swap partition/swap file on your system and is it enough big (your ram twice is okay).

Third important thing: before your mysql collapses, some loooooong query will be probably executed. It is especially so if there is also swap! Because if you have swap, and there your memory is leaking, your system won't collapse, only it will be a little bit slower. And luckily, mysql has a wonderful support to find out the queries whose execution is abnormal slow. These can be found in a file named `mysql-slow.log` or such somewhere below your `/var/log` directory.

Thus, enable swap, find out which query makes your mysql so slow, find out, what gives this query to your mysql daemon and you solved the problem.

Comment: I've just added enough swap, but running free -m shows that none of it is put to use. I've run swapon on the file, but do i need to enable swap somewhere else as well?

Comment: First, a `cat /proc/swaps` shows how many swaps are currently being used, and where. If it is empty, you had to turn it on. Before first enabling swap, an `mkswap filename` and a `sync` command should be also given. And you can enable swap permanently (after shutdowns) in `/etc/fstab`, but it will be a future. Currently you had to enable this swap finally.

Comment: mkswap has been called aswell as the sync command. The swap file/partition shows up as excepted in /proc/swaps. Could this be because the swap is not needed atm?

Comment: First: copy your /proc/swaps here, maybe it isn't enough big or used. Second: probably you have swap, thus can go further: see mysql-slow.log .

Comment: See my edit for /proc/swaps/. I don't have a mysql-slow.log file, or at least I can't find it. Shouldn't it reside in side /var/log/

Comment: Using the slow log i found a sucspius query, now a few weeks later I can tell that one of my applications were clogging up mysql. After uninstallning that app the problem has been gone. Thanks for your help! And thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

Could you paste your my.cnf file here? Maybe it would be great if you could paste apache config too. (Along with your machine specs).

You can use monit, and force it restarting mysql when oomkiller kills it, however it will not the greatest idea ever, because it won't solve the root cause of the problem - which is probably lack of RAM. Here I paste you a monit config sniplet what you can use for reloading killed mysql.

```
    check process mysql with pidfile /var/run/mysqld/mysql.pid
        group mysql
        start program = "/etc/init.d/mysql start"
        stop program = "/etc/init.d/mysql stop"
        if failed unix "/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock" then restart
        if 5 restarts within 5 cycles then timeout
```

But still, it would be better if you could fix the amount of RAM your system could use.